# BreezeJS and ASMX webservices

Tags: breeze

How do we consume ASMX webservices with BreezeJS?

Do we need to create a Web API controller, that will „talk“ to the ASMX webservices or can the breeze-client talk directly with the ASMX webservices?

We are thinking of using the data from the ASMX webservices as entities on the client.

As I understand BreezeJS uses JSON, while our ASMX webservice uses XML. I guess this is a problem?

Comment: Can you modify the ASMX service or is that out of your control?

Comment: The ASMX service is in our control. What modifications should be made to it?

Answer (score 0):

The ASMX service should be marked as a `ScriptService`, like so:

```
[WebService]  
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]  
public class MyWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
...
}
```